# Returning to Syncronous Operations after Async

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have one method which runs on 4 threads whilst the main thread does nothing:

```
    private void ConvThreadWorker(ConcurrentQueue<string> queue, ref ProgressData progData, ref ReferenceBool continued)
    {
        while (!queue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string file;
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out file))
            {
                ConvToG(file);
                UpdateUI(progData,queue.Count); //Using Control.Invoke(...)
            }
        }
        lock (continued)
        {
            if (!continued.Value)
            {
                continued.Value = true;
                PopulateControls(); //Run this on main thread
            }
        }
    }
```

Then once the `PopulateControls()` method is reached, I want to return to synchronicity and run this on the main thread (it's not a long operation so there is no concern about blocking).

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Why don't you use Control.Invoke again for calling PopulateControls in the main thread. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have considered doing that @Fernando, but it would require more refactoring than I think it would be worth (I've inherited a rather terrible codebase) if there's an easy way to just shoot it into the main thread. If not, then I'll have to do that.

Comment: Well, if you have a reference to Control it shouldn't be so complicated IMHO, just do refToControl.Invoke(() -> PopulateControls); or something like that (I don't remember the exact syntax)

Comment: It's not complicated at all, there are just a load of different controls I'd have to do it for. Plus, this is also for curiosity's sake.